# Compare string to null - Why does Resharper think this is always false?

Tags: c#, .net, string, resharper, membership-provider

I have this code in my custom MembershipProvider:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
{
    if (config == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("config");

    if (name == null)
        name = "MyCustomMembershipProvider";
    ...
}
```

Resharper marks the second if-Statement and tells me, it would always evaluate to false.

[image: resharper message]

But why would this always evaluate to false? I could easily pass null to the method as a parameter.

Is this a bug or is Resharper right here?

PS 1: I use Resharper 6.1
PS 2: I know using string.IsNullOrEmpty() would be the way to go here anyway. I'm just curious.

Comment: From which class is your class deriving? Is it one from you or one from the .NET framework?

Comment: Is that your complete code?  I'm using ReSharper 6.1 and don't get that indication.

Comment: I am deriving from MembershipProvider (in System.Web.Security)

Comment: [`ProviderBase.Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.provider.providerbase.initialize.aspx) throws also an `ArgumentNullException` when `name` is `null` (and an `ArgumentException` if it's empty). So i assume that Resharper knows that and assumes itself that a child shouldn't be less restrictive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably, the argument `name` is marked as `[NotNull]`. Resharper ships with contract metadata for common BCL classes.

Comment: Is there any reason it would mark this method parameter this way? It's a public method, what would stop anyone from calling it with a null parameter?

Comment: The contract metadata is not meant to be 100% accurate. It is meant to be pragmatic. I think that's a good thing.

Comment: Interestingly, ProviderBase ALSO does a NULL check for name despite the [NotNull] code contract.

Comment: Does this mean that the declaration of the `virtual` method in the base class decorates the first parameter with an attribute called `[NotNull]`? Or where is it that `[NotNull]` is specified?

Comment: I don't know. Of course, it is not in mscorlib.dll because that is shipped by Microsoft. Must be some external file that ships with R#. R# can take the metadata from wherever it likes, it does not need to play by the rules of csc.exe.